# Renaming Textboxes after deleting row

Tags: javascript, php

I wanted to rename my textboxes after deleting some rows..

`TextBoxA1 TextBoxB1`

`TextBoxA2 TextBoxB2`

`TextBoxA3 TextBoxB3`

then i delete TextBox2. Then I add a row and i got this

`TextBox1 TextBoxB1`

`TextBox3 TextBoxB3`

`TextBox3 TextBoxB3`

i wanted to rename it or rename their ids because im using each id's for Php and for a window.opener

the output should be like this again

`TextBoxA1 <before the name is TextBoxA1> TextBoxB1 <before the name is TextBoxB1>`

`TextBoxA2 <before the name is TextBoxA3> TextBoxB2 <before the name is TextBoxB3>`

`TextBoxA3 <newly added row> TextBoxB3 <newly added row>`

here's the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k3vin023/MvQ4h/5/

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish your goal using re-indexing: http://jsfiddle.net/MvQ4h/8/

Basically what I have done is added a small snippet of code that loops through all the input texts after you remove a text and update the values:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(i, ev) {
    var newId = 'txt' + (i + 1);
    $(this).attr('id', newId).val(newId);
});
```

Comment: what about if i have 2 textboxes in same td?

Comment: It should re-index by what is left after the remove.  Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: and also why it does affect all my textboxes? for example the txt1 is in table1 and my other textbox was affected too in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, you should re-assign the id(s) for all (or at least > i) textbox in your remove function.